# How to specify SchemaAction on a many-to-many link table?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm mapping some legacy views using SchemaAction.None() on the ClassMap, however there are also a few ManyToMany's using a legacy view as the link table. How can I exclude these link tables from the schema export?

For example...

```
HasManyToMany<Widget>(x => x.widgets)
    .Table("LegacyLinkView") //How to control the SchemaAction on this legacy link table?
```

or maybe there is a way to handle it in the Configuration? My last option would be to hand edit the resulting create scripts.

Comment: One approach i use is to exclude this class from the configuration, build the schema and add it later before creating the sessionfactory

Comment: ah ha! It works, I can exclude the one class and leave the other legacy views in there to complete the reference chains. Luckily the class with the many to many is not referenced by any other class. You want to post that comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach i use is to exclude this class from the configuration, build the schema and add it later before creating the sessionfactory.